# Google Analytics and XML namespace issue

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, google-analytics-api

I have looked through several posts on how to parse the namespace of a Google Analytics api feed (XML file) in PHP. They all say I need to have this bit of code:

```
$properties = $item->children('http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009');
```

(or something similar, all involving the URL "http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009")

The problem is, however, that I then get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function children() on a non-object

It seems as though the schemas.google.com doesn't exist, but I can't find where I need to be pointing to... any ideas?

Here's a snippet of the XML file I'm working with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:dxp="http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009" xmlns:openSearch="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
 <id>https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:42418300&amp;dimensions=ga:pagePath&amp;metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews&amp;sort=-ga:pageviews&amp;start-date=2013-12-01&amp;end-date=2014-01-01&amp;max-results=10</id>
 <updated>2014-01-03T22:21:31.057Z</updated>
 <title type="text">Google Analytics Data for View (Profile) xxxxxxx</title>
 <link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:42418300&amp;dimensions=ga:pagePath&amp;metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews&amp;sort=-ga:pageviews&amp;start-date=2013-12-01&amp;end-date=2014-01-01&amp;max-results=10"/>
 <link rel="next" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:42418300&amp;dimensions=ga:pagePath&amp;metrics=ga:pageviews,ga:uniquePageviews&amp;sort=-ga:pageviews&amp;start-date=2013-12-01&amp;end-date=2014-01-01&amp;start-index=11&amp;max-results=10"/>
 <author>
  <name>Google Analytics</name>
 </author>
 <generator>Google Analytics</generator>
 <openSearch:totalResults>4826</openSearch:totalResults>
 <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
 <openSearch:itemsPerPage>10</openSearch:itemsPerPage>
 <dxp:aggregates>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:pageviews" type="integer" value="166656"/>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:uniquePageviews" type="integer" value="132895"/>
 </dxp:aggregates>
 <dxp:containsSampledData>false</dxp:containsSampledData>
 <dxp:dataSource>
  <dxp:property name="ga:profileId" value="xxxxxxxx"/>
  <dxp:property name="ga:webPropertyId" value="UA-xxxxxxxx-1"/>
  <dxp:property name="ga:accountName" value="Provost"/>
  <dxp:tableId>ga:42418300</dxp:tableId>
  <dxp:tableName>WebSite</dxp:tableName>
 </dxp:dataSource>
 <dxp:endDate>2014-01-01</dxp:endDate>
 <dxp:startDate>2013-12-01</dxp:startDate>
 <entry>
  <id>https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:42418300&amp;ga:pagePath=/&amp;start-date=2013-12-01&amp;end-date=2014-01-01</id>
  <updated>2014-01-03T22:21:31.057Z</updated>
  <title type="text">ga:pagePath=/</title>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.google.com/analytics"/>
  <dxp:dimension name="ga:pagePath" value="/"/>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:pageviews" type="integer" value="38197"/>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:uniquePageviews" type="integer" value="29385"/>
 </entry>
 <entry>
  <id>https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v2.4/data?ids=ga:42418300&amp;ga:pagePath=/page2/&amp;start-date=2013-12-01&amp;end-date=2014-01-01</id>
  <updated>2014-01-03T22:21:31.057Z</updated>
  <title type="text">ga:pagePath=/page2/</title>
  <link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="http://www.google.com/analytics"/>
  <dxp:dimension name="ga:pagePath" value="/page2/"/>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:pageviews" type="integer" value="13964"/>
  <dxp:metric name="ga:uniquePageviews" type="integer" value="10974"/>
 </entry>
```

Here's my PHP so far:

```
<?php
        //ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
        $xml = simplexml_load_file("/ga-feed.xml");
        $namespaces = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
        foreach ($xml->entry as $key => $value) {
            $value->registerXPathNamespace('dxp', 'http://schemas.google.com/analytics/2009');
            echo $value->xpath('dxp:metric[pageviews]') . "<br />\n";
        }       
        ?>
```

Eventually, I need to be able run some calculations with pageviews and unique pageviews (show top 4 sites, a 5th "Other" would be a combination of all the other sites) against the overall pageviews/unique pageviews. Am I at least going in a semi-correct direction?

Update: In my foreach, I removed "feed" so it just says $xml->entry as $key, and now it will display a list of text:

> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array
>
> Array

Not quite what I'm looking for... but progress? lol

Comment: I would like to recommend you use the newer version of the API: http://goo.gl/ydki2f

Comment: please post a valid part of the XML and the rest of your PHP code.

Comment: I'm reviewing the updated API. I've also updated my post to include code I'm working with.